# ASP GridView Scrollable and fixed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I have the following jquery script implemented:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/colResizable-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').Scrollable();
    })
    </script>
```

And it works in the way that the Header realy is fixed but the header is somehow not compatible to the rest of the GriView:
[image]

### Edit

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="40" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" EnableModelValidation="False" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" CssClass="mydatagrid"
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerGrid" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Black">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Lfd_Nr." SortExpression="id" />
```

### Edit 2

Thats what I get in Chrome:[image]

It's stretch wide as .....

Comment: Can you show us your `html`? of the GridView generated / illustrated above?

Comment: see above (Edit)

Comment: On your [Edit 2] illustration, Can you show us the `html code` snippet for this?

Answer (score 0):

Before using Products like [DevExpress for WebForm Grids](https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/PagingAndScrolling/Scrolling.aspx) (*all your web form grid issues are solved with this type of product)*

I have done two things to scroll the out of the box WebForm Grids.

1. When using the out of the box Grid View I would render it in a browser, copy the HTML Table Code, then put that into a scrollable div.  Then on the Grid set ShowHeaders = false. This can work if you do not have dynamic columns.
2. There is a plugin I used [that works "ok" on ASPSnippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-inside-ASPNet-UpdatePanel-using-jQuery-Plugin.aspx). That code has an HTML Example and JavaScript / jQuery Plug-in. I tried to paste the snippet here but it is not formatting well.